# Date-period understands “before 2000” as [“2000-01-01/2000-12-31”]

Tags: date-range, api-ai

I am building an [api.ai](https://api.ai) agent, but I'm struggling to get unbounded `date-period` parameters understood correctly.

For example:

- `before 2000` is interpreted as `["2000-01-01/2000-12-31"]`
- `after 1999` is interpreted as `["1999-01-01/1999-12-31"]`
- `after January 2007` is interpreted as `["2007-01-01/2007-01-31"]`

This makes me think only the date (`2000`/`January 2007`) is used for calculating the date-range, ignoring the adverb (`before`/`after`).

### Is there a way to understand `before 2000` as `["0000-01-01/2000-01-01"]` (or at least `["1970-01-01/2000-12-31"]` if Epoch-based)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `before` and `after` isn't matched, you are right.

You can add a custom entity, like `temporal preposition`, to deal with this.

`before`: `prior to, previous to, earlier than, preparatory to, in preparation for, preliminary to, in anticipation of, in expectation of; in advance of, ahead of, leading up to`

`after`: `following, subsequent to, succeeding, at the close/end of, in the wake of, later than`

You may create a composite entity (see [in the docs](https://api.ai/docs/entities#dev-composite)).
There you can compose the new `preposition` entity with the `sys.date` entity. 
So you will bound them together logically.

Comment: So if I get you right, I should send this new entity to my fulfilment webhook and handle `temporal modifiers` in its code? I would expect a more direct solution, but I'll accept your answer if I don't get any!

Comment: Since you can't change the behavior of system entities.. You have to do something own. 

Additionally you can create a composite entity. I'll add this to the answer.